# How can I calculate the angle of a line/vector if the center of the image is not (0,0)?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, transformation

[Simple image about the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGmMm.png)

How can I calculate the alpha? My center of the image is (320,240) because it is a 640x480 image and the upper left corner is the (0,0).

I tried to calculate it with the parametric equation ( `x = r * cos(alpha)` ) and it worked until I reached `alpha > 180 degrees`.

How can I calculate it after 180 degrees?

In code:
`dist = math.sqrt((math.pow((centerDart[0] - centerPoint[0]),2) + math.pow((centerDart[1] - centerPoint[1]),2)))`

I wanted to transform the point with this: `centerDart[0]-320`

`angleFromCos = round(math.degrees(math.acos((centerDart[0]-320)/dist)),2)`

Answer (score 0):

Who cares what the center of the image is? You have two points on that line, which are, according to the image, $\;(320,\,240)\;,\;\;(0,\,480)\;$ , so you can already calculate the line's slope:

$$m:=\frac{480-240}{320}=\frac{24}{32}=\frac34$$

so the angle between the line and *any* line parallel to the $\;x-$ axis is given by $\;\beta=\arctan\frac34\;$ , and thus your angle is $\;\alpha=\beta+180^\circ\;$

Comment: This does not gives me the correct angle. The angle should be more than 180. and with this if I have the center point `(320,240)` and the P is `(246,290)` than I get 145 degrees which is not correct.

Comment: @Gabe Then you made some mistake: the angle is $\;217.87^\circ\;$ . Who knows what you did to calculate $\;\beta\;$ above. Observe that it is trivial the angle $\;\alpha\;$ obtained above is greater than $\;180^\circ\;$ since $\;\alpha=\beta+180^\circ\;$ and $\;\beta>0\;$ ...

Comment: I don't know what I do wrong... `atan((290-240)/(246-320))` in degrees is `-34.04` and if I add 180 to it than it's `145.95`

Comment: @Gabe I think the mistake is mine: in that picutre you linked it looked to me as if the line crosses through the center $\;(320,240)\;$ and the inferior left point $\;(0,480)\;$ , but this last one seems to be wrong. Anyway, the general method is above, but without knowing other point besides the center that's crossed by the line I can't say how to evaluate $\;\alpha\;$ .